# How to print element of database without foreach in PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach, printing

I have a problem to print my element. I get element in my database with this code:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT burgers.id as id1, burgers.nom as nom_burgers,ingredients.nom as nom_ingredient,composition.quantite as quantite from burgers join recettes on(burgers.id_recette=recettes.id_recette) join composition on(recettes.id_recette=composition.id_recette) join ingredients on(composition.id_ingredient=ingredients.id);";
    $response = $db->query($query);
    $response->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    foreach ($response as $row2) {
        //On crée un tableau qui contiendra toutes nos personnes
        $persons2[] = $row2;    
    }
    $response->closeCursor();

?>
```

My sql request get all of element that I need to print. This element are stock in a table 'persons2'.After I do a foreach to print all element in a table.

And I go this HTML and php code to print my element.

```
<table border="1" width="80%" class="tableau2">
    <tr>
        <th>burgers</th>
        <th>ingredient</th>
        <th>quantite</th>
</tr>
<?php
            foreach ($persons2 as $ET2)
                {
?>      
<tr>
    <td><?php echo($ET2['nom_burgers'])?></td>
    <td><?php echo($ET2['nom_ingredient'])?></td>
    <td><?php echo($ET2['quantite'])?></td>
                     <?php
            } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have this type of print. Its a table with my element print by my foreach.

```
burgers     ingredient  quantite
Big Fernand   steak        2
Big Fernand   pain         1
Big Fernand   totame       1
Big Fernand   oignons      2
Mamie Burger  steak        2
Mamie Burger  pain         2
Mamie Burger  oignons      1
Mamie Burger  sauceuranium 1
Mamie Burger  cornichon    1
Mamie Burger  pain         1
```

The problem is that I don't want to print a table like above but I want to print my element like that:

```
Big Fernant    Mamie Burger
steak  2       steak   2
pain   1       pain    2
totame 1       oignons 1
...            ...
```

Maybe I have to change my foreach? To print only 'nom_burgers' one time and print other elements below 'nom_burgers'?

Comment: What you need is a crosstab query. [Here is an example](https://evolt.org/node/26896)